# PyQt5: How to bold the placeholder of a QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Well as the title already tells, I want to bold the placeholder text of a `QComboBox`.
I can't see a way to bold the placeholder of a `QComboBox`. With `QFont` i can bold every item in the `QComboBox`, but I just want the placeholder being bold. `setPlaceholderText()` takes only one argument for the text itself.

My current code:

```
comboBox = QComboBox()
# - Bold whole combobox- 
# font = QFont()
# font.setBold(True)
# comboBox.setFont(font) 
comboBox.addItems(items)
comboBox.setPlaceholderText("Select text")
comboBox.setCurrentIndex(-1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Due of a bug in the library, `QComboBox` has to be overwritten in order to set a placeholder. I already had the class for overwriting `QComboBox` so I did a minor change to make the `placeholderText` bold.

```
class QComboBox(QComboBox):

    def __init__(self, boldPlaceholder: bool = False, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.boldPlaceholder = boldPlaceholder


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.palette().color(QPalette.Text))

        # draw the combobox frame, focusrect and selected etc.
        opt = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        painter.drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_ComboBox, opt)

        if self.currentIndex() < 0:
            opt.palette.setBrush(
                QPalette.ButtonText,
                opt.palette.brush(QPalette.ButtonText).color().lighter()
            )

            if self.placeholderText():
                opt.currentText = self.placeholderText()

            # bold placeholdertText
            if self.boldPlaceholder and self.placeholderText():
                font = self.font()
                font.setBold(True)
                painter.setFont(font)


        # draw the icon and text
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ComboBoxLabel, opt)
```

Answer (score 1):

QComboBox doesn't provide so, and there are only two possibilities:

1. use a QProxyStyle and override [`drawControl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawControl) whenever a `CE_ComboBoxLabel` is being drawn, by checking if the combo has an invalid index and a place holder text;

```
class ComboStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, ce, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if (ce == self.CE_ComboBoxLabel and 
            widget.currentIndex() < 0 and 
            widget.placeholderText()):
                qp.save()
                font = widget.font()
                font.setBold(True)
                qp.setFont(font)
                super().drawControl(ce, opt, qp, widget)
                qp.restore()
        else:
            super().drawControl(ce, opt, qp, widget)

# ...
app.setStyle(ComboStyle())
# or, alternatively
combo.setStyle(ComboStyle())
```

2. use a subclass and change the font depending on the situations:

```
class ComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._defaultFont = self.font()
        self._boldFont = self.font()
        self._boldFont.setBold(True)
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.checkFont)
        self.checkFont(self.currentIndex())

    def checkFont(self, index):
        if index < 0 and self.placeholderText():
            self.setFont(self._boldFont)
        else:
            self.setFont(self._defaultFont)

    def setPlaceholderText(self, placeholderText):
        super().setPlaceholderText(placeholderText)
        self.checkFont(self.currentIndex())

    def showPopup(self):
        self.setFont(self._defaultFont)
        super().showPopup()

    def hidePopup(self):
        super().hidePopup()
        self.checkFont(self.currentIndex())
```

<sup>NOTE: Due to a bug in the latest Qt5 release (which was fixed for the commercial version of Qt, but it's not clear if it will be released for the open source version too), I've not been able to test the above.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It worked except of a little thing: When clicking on the combo box the placeholder isn't bold anymore. However, I could fix it myself (see below). But is there a way to set a specific part of the `placeholdeText` bold? E.g. (in markdown): `"**Hello** World!"`